# Run a binary with arguments using absolute path

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script, scripting

This is a embedded Linux system so things are a little different. I am trying to run an binary with arguments using absolute path but it doesn't work. If I run the binary from the folder it works e.g. if the binary is in `/home/root/test folder` and I run

```
root@user:~/test# ./mybinary 1  2
```

it works with no issue. But below will not work, seems it is not able to understand the arguments

```
root@user:~# /home/root/test/mybinary 1 2
```

In the end I want to run this binary using `crontab` where I would use the absolute path to call it.

Comment: As you point out, this binary program is being invoked by the shell successfully, and the command-line arguments (`1 2`) are exactly the same as when you invoke it with your current working directory in the same folder where the program is installed.  It's a matter of the code in the program itself having trouble with how you're invoking it, not the shell or the Linux kernel.  Does the program's documentation discuss its requirements about where your working directory must be?  Is this a program you have written?

Comment: @ilkkachu This is a embedded Linux system so things are a little different. Issue is, I cannot run this from anywhere except directory where it is present. If I run 
test/mybinary 1 2, it will not work. I believe it is something to do with how to run binaries with arguments from any path.

Comment: Please don't add information in the comments, @adi_226. The note about it being an embedded system was _really important_ and could have got lost amongst comments rather than being [edited into your question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/736375/edit). Please do tell us what exactly you mean by "_But below will not work, seems it is not able to understand the arguments_". Error messages?

Comment: @SottoVoce Thank you for your response. I believe that was the issue. 
So the binary tries to read information from files on the system. I didn't had those files mentioned as absolute paths in my code and there it was facing issue and giving the error. I changed those paths to absolute paths and it is working .

Comment: Do this work with your root cronjob? `cd "$HOME/test" && ./mybinary 1  2`

Comment: @ilkkachu the issue was with the binary using relative paths inside, therefore if I ran it from any other path it didn't work. It worked once I replaced relative paths in my code with absolute paths and used that binary. Thank you

Comment: @adi_226, ok, good. One common way to do that would be to have an environment variable tell the program where to look for the files it needs, so that it wouldn't be locked to expecting them in the working directory. (Or a configuration file in `/etc`. Or a command-line argument, but that's more of a nuisance for the user.)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because because it's now working; the OP pointed out that the "arguments" are filenames and that adding the full path to the arguments as well resolved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

If your program need to be started from a certain directory, maybe because it is reading some files from there with relative paths, just change the directory first:

```
cd /home/root/test; mybinary 1 2
```

You may add another cd to change back after finishing:

```
cd /home/root/test; mybinary 1 2; cd -
```

The latter is superflous if running from crontab, but in that case you have to combine the 2 commands into one:

```
(cd /home/root/test; mybinary 1 2)
```

Creating a seperate script for this purpose seems overengineering.

Don't forget a comment in the crontab. If you are the author  of said program, you should read from fixed config file like ~/.mybinaryrc or ~/.mybinary.conf or the like, or provide a directory switch, where to look for the files, so you can call it like that:

```
 mybinary --startdir ~/home/root/test 1 2
```